# mysql Add text to fields before string that does not contain a specified string

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I know I can add text to all fields using this SQL query

`update oc_product set sku= CONCAT('BBC', sku);`

but I need it to only add if the field does not contain BBC in it.

As all SKU is added on auto and I am unable to change the way they are added to my DB so I need to do it manually every day.

thanks in advance for any help.

ie:

123456
bbc123456
1234567
bbc987654

I need to only add BBC to those where it is not listed using phpmyadmin.

Comment: `WHERE sku NOT LIKE 'bbc%'`

Comment: Thanks very much appericated update oc_product set sku= CONCAT('BBC', sku) WHERE sku NOT LIKE 'bbc%';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `where` clause.  If you are looking for `'BBC'` anywhere in the string, then:

```
update oc_product
    set sku = CONCAT('BBC', sku)
    where sku not like '%BBC%';
```

If you are only looking for `'BBC'` at the beginning of the string, then:

```
update oc_product
    set sku = CONCAT('BBC', sku)
    where sku not like 'BBC%';
```